# Sequelize - Is there any way to do Data Abstraction/Filtering?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, doctrine, filtering, sequelize.js

First at all, I'm sorry if I'm re-posting, but I couldn't find anything related.

I'm working on a application that handle very sensitive data. I want to filter this data by user's role.

I've done this (in another job) using [Doctrine Filters](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html), but I can't find any information about how to do this using Sequelize (over PostgreSQL).

Eg:

```
sensitive_information:

| user_id | sensible_value |
+---------+----------------+
| 1       | something      |
| 2       | something_else |
```

I need this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sensitive_information
  WHERE user_id = 1; /** I need this to be added automatically in all
                         queries to sensitive_information */
```

So, user 1 never will see information of another user. That's the goal.

Is it possible? I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at scopes. I think it might help. Here is the link http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/scopes/

Comment: Yes @Hanna, I've saw it. But it requires that data consumers explicit use its allowed scope. If scope it's not specified then they will be seen the entirely data. I want something lowest level.

Answer (score 0):

This can be addressed by using [Sequelize scopes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html).

Since scopes can be functions:

> Scopes are defined in the model definition and can be finder objects, or functions returning finder objects

it's easy to define a scope that filters information according to the user that is logged in.

I haven't implemented this exactly scope yet but I have a good idea on how to address it if anyone needs helps with it.